# Show that a continuous function has a local minimal value between a maximal and minimal local values.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be continous on $[a,b]$, and $p,q\in[a,b]$. If $f$ has a local maximum on $p$ and a local minimum on $q$, show that there exists $ r\in[{\color{red}{p,q}}]$ such that $f$ has a local minimum on $r$.

I wrote the question exactly as it is written, but I think it is wrong, $p$ and $q$ should be both local maximum. Does anybody agree with it?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just let $r=q $, and be done? There might be another local minimum, but you just need one, and $q $ is the one.

Comment: The question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If $f$ has a local minimum on $[a,b]$, then $f$ has a local minimum on $[a,b]$ -- that's certainly true, but it doesn't require much of a proof, does it? As @AlexS said, just let $r=q$. Or check what the actual question was...

Comment: I have edited. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to assume that both $p, q$ are local maxima, otherwise question as given is trivially solved by taking $r=q$ and moreover if $f$ is strictly monotone on $[p, q] $ then $q$ is the only local minima.

Comment: @Paramanand thank you for your answer. I think the same, but I was not sure, which is why I wrote the question to see other person's opinion.

Comment: So you may perhaps edit the edit question accordingly and seek an answer to the updated question. Or if you already know the answer to the question I suggested in my previous comment then we are already done.

Comment: I do not know the answer. You are right, I will edit it